# Python 2.7.5 quit on user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a program return the luminance of a light based on user given values, but the while loop is what's getting me confused.

```
def Brightness(r,g,b):
    value = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
    return value


while True:
    r = int(raw_input("Enter in the value for red: "))
    g = int(raw_input("Enter in the value for green: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter in the value for blue: "))
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
    print result
    if ((r == "quit") or (g == "quit") or (b == "quit")):
        break

result = Brightness(r,g,b)
```

I feel like the answer is staring me right in the face, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: it only crashes for me when I supply something other than a number (i.e. 'f').  Is this what yore experiencing ?

Comment: For future reference, also include the error (e.g. `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'bad'`) when posting a question.  In this case it makes it pretty clear what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that you're doing `int(raw_input())` everywhere. This means that when you try to enter *quit* as input, the program will raise a `ValueError exception` and quit abnormally.

My suggestion is to modify a little bit the input loop:

```
while True:
    i1 = raw_input("Enter in the value for red: ")
    i2 = raw_input("Enter in the value for green: ")
    i3 = raw_input("Enter in the value for blue: ")
    if ((i1 == "quit") or (i2 == "quit") or (i3 == "quit")):
        break
    r = int(i1)
    g = int(i2)
    b = int(i3)
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
    print result

result = Brightness(r,g,b)
```

Also I don't understand what the last line `result = Brightness(r,g,b)` is for? It seems to me you're outputting the result in the last two lines in the loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here was the problem! I have no idea why the last line was there; maybe I forgot that it was there... Regardless, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you typecast all your user input to an int without validating the input. When the input is a string, python will throw an error, because a string cannot be converted to an integer.

Best would be to store the raw input as raw data into the variables r, g, and b and check whether the user wants to quit first. If not, you should do a sanity check on your input values. If they are integers, you can typecast them as such. Otherwise, print an error message or start at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code can't possibly work correctly.  If the user enters `quit`, then when you pass that input string to `int()` you will get an exception, because `quit` doesn't work as an integer.

Then, if the user does enter `quit`, you can break out of the loop without setting all of `r`, `g`, and `b`, so the last line where you call `Brightness(r,g,b)` will raise an exception.

Also, this doesn't check to see if the user entered `quit` until after the user has been prompted three times.  This will annoy a user who wanted to quit at the first number.

So, don't convert the user's input to integer without checking for `quit`; check after each time you prompt the user; and either have default values for `r`,`g`, and `b` or else don't have the last call to `Brightness()` if the user quit.

```
QUIT = "quit"

got_input = False
while True:
    r = raw_input("Enter in the value for red: ")
    if r == QUIT:
        break
    r = int(r)

    g = raw_input("Enter in the value for green: ")
    if g == QUIT:
        break
    g = int(g)

    b = raw_input("Enter in the value for blue: ")
    if b == QUIT:
        break
    b = int(b)

    got_input = True
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
    print result

if got_input:
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
```

Note that there is a lot of repetition in this loop.  Perhaps we could write a function to clean it up?

```
def get_user_input(question)
    answer = raw_input(question)
    if answer == QUIT:
        return False, None
    else:
        return True, int(answer)

got_input = False
while True:
    quit, r = get_user_input("Enter in the value for red: ")
    if quit:
        break

    quit, g = get_user_input("Enter in the value for green: ")
    if quit:
        break

    b = get_user_input("Enter in the value for blue: ")
    if quit:
        break

    got_input = True
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
    print result

if got_input:
    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
```

It's a little better.  Maybe we can make it cleaner?  Let's use Python exceptions.  We can just write the code to assume that things are going as planned, but when the user enters `quit` we can raise an exception.  Let's define our own exception to make this clear.

```
import sys
QUIT = "quit"

class UserHasQuit(Exception):
    pass

def get_user_input(question)
    answer = raw_input(question)
    if answer == QUIT:
        raise UserHasQuit
    return int(answer)

try:
    r = get_user_input("Enter in the value for red: ")
    g = get_user_input("Enter in the value for green: ")
    b = get_user_input("Enter in the value for blue: ")

    result = Brightness(r,g,b)
    print result
except UserHasQuit:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Instead of `raise UserHasQuit` we could call `sys.exit()` when getting user input.  But when you are debugging, an exception gives you a stack backtrace that shows you where the exception came from, while `sys.exit()` just makes the program stop.  So if you have an unexpected `sys.exit()` it can be a bit hard to find it, but exceptions are easy to find.  So it's best to keep calls to `sys.exit()` at the outer layer and use exceptions for internal code.